# Add constraints for every other day for Google OR Tools "Employee Scheduling"

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools

How do I add constraints to Google OR-tool example?
https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

I want to add this:

- shift1: can work every day.
- shift2: can only work every other day.
  Need to work 2 days in one week and must start on Monday or Tuesday.

[image]

.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple implication:

```
work[nurse, day, shift2] => not(work[nurse, day + 1, shift2])
```

Now

must start on Monday or Tuesday

```
BoolOr([work[nurse, Monday, shifts], work[nurse, Tuesday, shift2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand how I should use it in the example so I haven't managed to try it